# simple-git: SSH authentication example using simple-git

Tags: javascript, node.js, simple-git

How to clone a repository with **SSH** using **simple-git**?

I'm trying to clone using this code

```
const git: SimpleGit = simpleGit();
const sshUri = 'git@..........'
const localPath = '/usr/workspace';
git
 .clone(
   sshUri,
   localPath
 ).then((data) => {
    console.log('success');
 }).catch((err) => {
     console.log(err);
 });
```

But I am getting an exception

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 2):

If your git repo is private, you will need to generate SSH key and add this key to your GIT account.

- To generate SSH Key:
  https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh
- Add your SSH to git account:
  You can find it here
  https://github.com/settings/keys

Code example

```
    private async cloneRepo() {

        const gitSSH = 'FILL YOUR SSH GIT ADDRESS';
        const sourceDir = path.resolve(`${os.tmpdir()}/${this.projectKey}`);
        const sshKnownHosts = path.resolve(`${process.cwd()}/settings/ssh/known_hosts`)
        const sshKey = path.resolve(`${process.cwd()}/settings/ssh/id_ed25519`)

        const GIT_SSH_COMMAND = `ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=${sshKnownHosts} -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i ${sshKey}`;

        console.log(sourceDir);

        const git: SimpleGit = simpleGit()
            .env('GIT_SSH_COMMAND', GIT_SSH_COMMAND)
            .clean(CleanOptions.FORCE);

        await git.clone(gitSSH, sourceDir, ['-b', 'YOUR-BRANCH-NAME', '--single-branch'])
            .then(() => console.log('finished'))
            .catch((err) => console.error('failed: ', err));
    }
```